# how to read params from a nested route in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

i have my routing defined like this:

```
export const router = Router();

const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    router: usersRouter,
  },
  {
    path: "/games/",
    router: gamesRouter,
  },
  {
    path: "/games/:gameId/pieces/",
    router: piecesRouter
  }
];

appRoutes.forEach((route) => router.use(route.path, route.router));
```

when i send a request to eg "/games/4/pieces/" the correct action from the controller is being picked up, and when i log `req` object i can see that the `gameId` is there:

```
baseUrl: '/games/4/pieces',
originalUrl: '/games/4/pieces',
_parsedUrl: Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: '/',
  _raw: '/'
},
params: {},
query: {},
```

HOWEVER its not in the params and when i read `req.params` its just an empty hash. its as if Express.js read only params listed in the nested router itself which looks like this:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { index } from "../controllers/pieces.controller";

export const piecesRouter = Router();

piecesRouter.get("/", index);
```

the path passed to `get` method does not have any vars so i dont get any in the params. how can i access these params?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `{ mergeParams: true }` option to the `express.Router()`.

> Preserve the `req.params` values from the parent router. If the parent and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take precedence.

The option is available for express *4.5.0+*. The default value is `false`.

E.g.

```js
import express, { Router } from 'express';

const app = express();

const router = Router();
const piecesRouter = Router({ mergeParams: true });

piecesRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

router.use('/games/:gameId/pieces/', piecesRouter)

app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is listening on http://localhost:3000'))
```

Send a `GET` HTTP request to `http://localhost:3000/games/4/pieces` endpoint, the server logs:

```bash
Server is listening on http://localhost:3000
{ gameId: '4' }
```